# Status Code 400 when uploading an image to an API

Tags: objective-c

I'm trying to upload an image to an image recognition API, but I'm getting this is the `NSHTTPURLResponse` I'm getting.

```
<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x12f7ce4e0> { URL: https:/api.vize.ai/v1/classify/ } { status code: 400, headers {
    Allow = "POST, OPTIONS";
    Connection = "keep-alive";
    "Content-Language" = en;
    "Content-Length" = 37;
    "Content-Type" = "application/json";
    Date = "Wed, 21 Feb 2018 12:24:17 GMT";
    "Referrer-Policy" = "strict-origin";
    Server = "nginx/1.13.7";
    "Strict-Transport-Security" = "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload";
    Vary = "Accept, Host, Accept-Language, Cookie";
    "X-Frame-Options" = DENY;
    "X-UA-Compatible" = "IE=Edge,chrome=1";
    "x-content-type-options" = nosniff;
    "x-xss-protection" = "1; mode=block";
} }
```

I'm using an image picker to select an image, and then upload that. Here's my implementation of that.

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)info
{
    // Dismiss image picker
    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

    // Classify image
    UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage"];

    // Request authorization
    [PHPhotoLibrary requestAuthorization:^(PHAuthorizationStatus status) {
        switch (status) {
                case PHAuthorizationStatusAuthorized:
                NSLog(@"PHAuthorizationStatusAuthorized");
                break;
                case PHAuthorizationStatusDenied:
                NSLog(@"PHAuthorizationStatusDenied");
                break;
                case PHAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined:
                NSLog(@"PHAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined");
                break;
                case PHAuthorizationStatusRestricted:
                NSLog(@"PHAuthorizationStatusRestricted");
                break;
        }
    }];

    // Get image name
    NSURL *refURL = [info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL];
    PHFetchResult *result = [PHAsset fetchAssetsWithALAssetURLs:@[refURL] options:nil];
    NSString *filename = [[result firstObject] filename];

    // Get image file path and append file name onto it
    NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0);
    NSString *path = [NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:filename];
    [imageData writeToFile:path atomically:YES];

    NSDictionary *headers = @{ @"content-type": @"multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW",
                               @"Content-Type": @"multipart/form-data",
                               @"Accept": @"application/json",
                               @"Authorization": @"Token 60f6be2a21bdf731d86a8817b440a1afba692fed",
                               @"Cache-Control": @"no-cache",
                               @"Postman-Token": @"7d262730-0c7d-66dc-bbbb-43f40dbfe8ce" };
    NSArray *parameters = @[ @{ @"name": @"task", @"value": @"dc9ef71a-b8a0-4a12-90fd-83d717cf887f" },
                             @{ @"name": @"image_file", @"fileName": path } ];
    NSString *boundary = @"----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW";    

    NSError *error;
    NSMutableString *body = [NSMutableString string];
    for (NSDictionary *param in parameters) {
        [body appendFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary];
        if (param[@"fileName"]) {
            [body appendFormat:@"Content-Disposition:form-data; name=\"%@\"; filename=\"%@\"\r\n", param[@"name"], param[@"fileName"]];
            [body appendFormat:@"Content-Type: %@\r\n\r\n", param[@"contentType"]];
            [body appendFormat:@"%@", [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:param[@"fileName"] encoding:/*NSASCIIStringEncoding*/NSASCIIStringEncoding error:&error]]; // here NSUTF8StringEncoding

            if (error) {
                NSLog(@"%@", error);
            }
        } else {
            [body appendFormat:@"Content-Disposition:form-data; name=\"%@\"\r\n\r\n", param[@"name"]];
            [body appendFormat:@"%@", param[@"value"]];
        }
    }
    [body appendFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n", boundary];
    NSData *postData = [body dataUsingEncoding:/*NSASCIIStringEncoding*/NSASCIIStringEncoding]; // here NSUTF8StringEncoding

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.vize.ai/v1/classify/"]
                                                           cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                                       timeoutInterval:10.0];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setAllHTTPHeaderFields:headers];
    [request setHTTPBody:postData];

    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
    NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request
                                                completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
                                                    if (error) {
                                                        NSLog(@"%@", error);
                                                    } else {
                                                        NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *) response;
                                                        NSLog(@"%@", httpResponse);
                                                    }
                                                }];
    [dataTask resume];
}
```

What's my problem here?

Comment: There is something wrong with your request. Therefore the server responds with HTTP 400 (Bad request) See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/400 Have a look at the API documentation and change your request accordingly.

Comment: @marcusficner I understand that, but there is little documentation on this specific API regarding this specific problem.

Comment: @marcusficner I'm using the [Vize API](https://vize.ai). Do you know if how I'm passing an image is correct?

Comment: @marcusficner also, this code snippet was generated by Postman, an API testing tool.

Answer (score 0):

Using afnetworking for this. 
here is working code :

```
    -(void)uploadImagetoServer

    {

        if(self.titleTextField.text.length>0)
        {

    self.descrptionTxtview.center = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.view.bounds), CGRectGetMidY(self.view.bounds));
           // NSString *firstName=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"username"]];
            //NSString *lastName=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"lastname"]];



NSString *fullname=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@  %@",[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"firstname"],[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"lastname"]];

                NSString * type ;


            NSString * userId = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@",[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"userid"]];
          //  lastName= [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@ %@", firstName, lastName];
            userInfoDict=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
            [userInfoDict setValue:userId forKey:@"user_id"];
             [userInfoDict setValue:fullname forKey:@"username"];
            [userInfoDict setValue:@"29" forKey:@"catid"];
             [userInfoDict setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@", self.titleTextField.text] forKey:@"title"];
            [_request setTimeoutInterval:1000];
            NSLog(@"Parameters :%@",userInfoDict);
            NSString * baseUrl = @"https://justgolive.net/api/Home/videoUpload/";
            _request = [[AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer] multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST" URLString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",baseUrl] parameters:userInfoDict constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData)
                        {
                            NSLog(@"\n\n requrst time out is%f\n\n", [_request timeoutInterval]);


                            NSData* data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(_imagedRecived);

                            [formData appendPartWithFileData:data name:@"video" fileName:@"myImage.png" mimeType:@"image/png"];

                            NSLog(@"\n image  upload %@\n\n",_videoUrl);

                        } error:nil];


           // [self.view addSubview:_playerProgress];
           // [_playerProgress setHidden:NO];
            self.descrptionTxtview.center = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.view.bounds), CGRectGetMidY(self.view.bounds));
            AFURLSessionManager *manager = [[AFURLSessionManager alloc] initWithSessionConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];

            _uploadTask = [manager
                           uploadTaskWithStreamedRequest:_request
                           progress:^(NSProgress * _Nonnull uploadProgress)

                           {
                               // This is not called back on the main queue.
                              // You are responsible for dispatching to the main queue for UI updates
                               dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{


                               //    [_btn_sendbutton setHidden:YES];


                                   //Update the progress view
                              //     [_playerProgress setProgress:uploadProgress.fractionCompleted];



                             //      [self.view addSubview:_largestProgressView];

                             //      [_largestProgressView setProgress:uploadProgress.fractionCompleted animated:YES];
                                  NSLog(@"\n uploading image vlaues %f\n",uploadProgress.fractionCompleted);

                                   // for uploading video in background
                                   [self.uploProgressView setHidden:NO];
                                   [self.uploProgressView setProgress:uploadProgress.fractionCompleted animated:YES];
                                   if (uploadProgress.completedUnitCount == 1) {
                                       //  [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
                                   }
                                  manager.attemptsToRecreateUploadTasksForBackgroundSessions=YES;


                               });
                         }
                          completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse * _Nonnull response, id  _Nullable responseObject, NSError * _Nullable error) {
                               if (error) {
                                   NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
                                 self.descrptionTxtview.center = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.view.bounds), CGRectGetMidY(self.view.bounds));

                                 // [_playerProgress setHidden:YES];

                               } else
                               {

                                   NSLog(@"%@ ", response);
                                   manager.attemptsToRecreateUploadTasksForBackgroundSessions=NO;
                                   [_playerProgress setHidden:YES];

                                   NSLog(@"\n\n REsponse Form Server %@\n\n",responseObject);
                                   NSArray * ressp = responseObject;
                                   NSError *error;
                                   [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtURL:_videoUrl error:&error];
                                   if ([[ressp valueForKey:@"message"] isEqualToString:@"Successfull"]) {
                                       [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
                                   }
                                 [model setUpLogin:YES];
                                 //


                               }
                           }


                           ];

            [_uploadTask resume];

           [self hideStuffOndoneUploading];

        }
        else
           [self alertControllerMethod:@"Please add story description and try again" forTitle:@"Warning" withTag:nil];


    }
```

Comment: What is `model`?

Comment: i have updated my answer. model class was singleton class for saving some data. i have removed it from the code

Comment: I have asked a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48940176/status-code-400-when-converting-postman-request-into-objective-c) here. Would you mind taking a look at it? I am trying to use code generated by Postman to upload an image to the API.